# Are my answers referencing a given Venn Diagram, correct?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Please help me to understand if my answers are correct:

In the diagram, each number indicates the umber of elements in each region. 
$$n(A)=14,\;\; n(B)=17,\; \;n(C)=14,\;\; n(U)=35$$

$$n(A\cup B)=26, \;\;n(A\cup C)=25, \;\;n(B\cup C)=23, \;\;n(A\cap B)=7, \;\;n(A\cap C)=5,$$ $$n(A\cap B\cap C)=3, \;\;n(A\cup B\cup C)=30, \;\;n((A\cup B)\cap C)=10, \;\;n((A\cap B)\cup C)=10$$
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: The first and last statements are false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per David's comment, two of your answers (first and last) are wrong. Instead:  $$n(A) = 7+4+2+3 = 16 \;\text{ and }\;n((A\cap B)\cup C)= 4+3+2+5+4 = 18.$$